# psycopg2 error : literal carriage return found in data

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, psycopg2

I am trying to push data from a python dataframe to Postgres database using psycopg2 and sqlalchemy.
This is the script -

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import psycopg2 as pg
import io

address = 'postgresql://username:password@dbname.endpoint.rds.amazonaws.com:5432/dbname'
engine = create_engine(address)
connection = engine.raw_connection()
cursor = connection.cursor()

df_tbl.reset_index(inplace=True)

command = '''create table data.table_name(
index bigint,
pid varchar,
name varchar);'''
cursor.execute(command)
connection.commit()


output = io.StringIO()

df_tbl.to_csv(output, sep=',', header=False, index=False)

output.seek(0)
contents = output.getvalue()
cur = connection.cursor()

cur.copy_from(output, 'data.table_name', sep=',', null='')
connection.commit()
cur.close()
```

I get this error -

```
psycopg2.errors.BadCopyFileFormat: literal carriage return found in data HINT: Use "\r" to represent carriage return.
```

I tried using line_terminator = '\r' but it did not work. What can I do?

Comment: What OS are you using? the default line terminator depends on OS. If you try line_terminator="\n" do you still see this error?

Comment: Yes I still see the error after line_terminator="\n". I have MacOS

Comment: Exactly the same error - with "\r"? If so that should tell us that the rogue carriage returns are not part of the line terminator but appear somewhere within the data. I'd suggest you try debugging by searching for \r in your text stream. Is it possible that there are actually carriage returns in your data? Does your data contain free-form text for example?

Comment: `django.db.connection.copy_from()` does not like newlines (`\n` or `\r`) in the text of its fields. I am looking into a way around this and will write an answer if I find it.